# Use function when margin of object is changed (loop)

Tags: jquery, loops, image-gallery, margin, page-numbering

In my image carousel, the main thing that changes is the value of the `margin-left`. From knowing this value, I wanted to try to interpret a slide number (like 'Image 3 of 4').
I got the number of all slides with:

```
var all_slides_width = $('#gallery_wrapper').outerWidth();
var slide_width = $('.image_content').outerWidth();
var slide_quantity = all_slides_width / slide_width;
```

Then I wanted to get the number of the currently visible image with:

```
var margin_left = parseInt($('#gallery_wrapper').css('margin-left'));
var slide_count = parseInt(-margin_left + slide_width) / slide_width;
```

and displaying it with:

```
<span class="slide_number"></span>
<script>
    $( '.slide_number' ).text( 'Image ' + slide_count + " of " + slide_quantity);
</script>
```

The problem is, that the `margin-left` changes with every new slide. So I need a loop that changes the `slide_count` every time the `margin-left`changes. How can I achieve this?
A `setTimeout` of every second was obviously very inefficient. Here's a fiddle of my current status: http://jsfiddle.net/cqgnvsce/

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted your timeout and self-call from slide_number(). Is that what you were trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/76zfn6ga/ You're already calling slide_count whenever you call slide() so I don't see a need for a loop. In fact, why don't you call slide_number() from within slide()?

```
var slide_number = function () {
    var margin_left = parseInt($('#gallery_wrapper').css('margin-left'));
    var slide_count = parseInt(-margin_left + slide_width) / slide_width;
    $('.slide_number').text('Image ' + slide_count + " of " + slide_quantity);
};
```

Comment: The problem that occured now, is that everything is shifted – image 2 is now image 1, etc… And I actually would like to see "Image 1 of 1" when the first slide is loaded? Do you have an idea how that could be implemented?

Comment: But putting slide_number() into slide() is still a very good idea! :)

Comment: I bet you can get that on your own.